# Django model inheritance vs composition, and querying multiple models/tables together

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, composition, schema-design

I have a Django app that has a number of different models, all with a bunch of common data. Ultimately, I think this question comes down to a decision between inheritance and composition. My current implementation is something like this:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    foo = models.FooField()
    bar = models.BarField()
    type = models.CharField()

class A(CommonStuff):
    aFoo = models.FooField()

class B(CommonStuff):
    bFoo = models.FooField()
```

With this model, I'm able to query for a `Thing` using the Thing model's manager. Using the type field on `Thing`, I can get the child object data by looking at the `type` field, which contains either 'a' or 'b', and then asking for (i.e.) `thing.a.aFoo`. This is a feature I like because it's a fairly common operation in my app to get a list of all `Thing` objects.

I see a couple couple issues here. First, the `type` field seems unnecessary. Is there way to get at the child data without having to first look up the type? It seems like I could work around this with an instance method that returned the correct object given its type value, or if I really wanted to get rid of the type field, I could iterate over each of the reverse relation fields on `Thing`, looking for one that doesn't raise a `DoesNotExist` exception. This feels quite brittle to me though. If I add a new 'subthing' `C`, I have to update `Thing` to look for the new type. I could fix this by making `Thing` and abstract model. That way, `A` and `B` get all the fields of `Thing` and I avoid having to use the `type` field. Problem, though, is that I lose the ability to perform queries for all `Thing` objects.

Another model I'm thinking about sort of flips this one on its head by turning the data in `Thing` into a field on `A` and `B`.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    foo = models.FooField()
    bar = models.BarField()

class A(models.Model):
    aFoo = models.FooField()
    thing = models.OneToOneField(Thing)

class B(models.Model):
    bFoo = models.FooField()
    thing = models.OneToOneField(Thing)
```

This version has a few benefits. It gets rid of the `type` field on `Thing`, and—at least to me—looks and feels cleaner and less brittle. The problem here, though, is the same as the problem with making `Thing` abstract in the first version. I lose the ability to query all my 'subthings' together. I can do a query for `A` objects or a query for `B` objects, but not both. Can use this version of the model without having to sacrifice the ability to query for all 'subthings'? One possibility is to write a manager that queries both models and returns a `QuerySet` of all the objects. Does that work?

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is the you can do things like for(Thing model in [Things]){

Comment: I know. But I need a nice way of getting to the attributes of the child. Inheritance is not so great at that.

Comment: are you looking to query on the subclasses from `Thing.objects`, or just be able to access the proper subclass from an instance of a `Thing`, or both?

Comment: Mostly the latter, though I've spent a fair bit of time trying to write a Manager that will return instances of the subclasses.

Comment: The `QuerySet` approach doesn't seem to be efficient. While I agree that the first solution is brittle, it is what I think the best option here.

Comment: Did you resolve this question? I have this same problem many years later.